# select unique row identifier in mysql for updating

Tags: mysql

in infomix i have seen queries like this

```
select rowid from table where condition
```

and for update they use the same row id

```
update table set field="val" where rowid=rowid
```

is there anything similar in mysql database

does `uuid` function does the same in mysql .

actually my problem is, there is no primary key in the table so when porting infomix query to mysql i need to consider all the fields in where condition  .
please help if there is an alternate solution ,

Comment: If there is no primary key, you will have to query all known fields.

Comment: Do you know the specific row that you need to update?

Comment: ya am selecting that before update

Comment: Is it a possibility for you to alter your table to define a surrogate primary key with an auto_increment field, and use 
that to reference your row for subsequent updates?

Comment: sir actually that's the problem the system was designed in 1991 using 4gl and infomix client doesn't want any altration to database table.

Comment: can't add unique index neiter?

Comment: You might need to add a unique compound index. How many rows does this table have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are porting your queries from informix to mysql, why don't you modify your tables to include a primary key?

you could even name the PK `rowid` to maintain portability between the informix and mysql queries.

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD rowid MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
```

Answer (score 1):

why not...

```
select  rowid  from  table  where  condition
                                      |
                                      V
update table set field="val" where condition
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use same condition for both query which you pass on first query, it returns you unique row..
```

try this

```
select  rowid  from  table  where  condition
```

and for update  use the same condition as above instead of `row id`

```
update table set field="val" where rowid=rowid
```